# Check if a type is a supertype of another using typetag

Tags: scala

Since the `>:>` method of `ClassTag` is deprecated and the operation is not supported by `TypeTag`, how can I check if a runtime type is a supertype of another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scala>  def checkType[S: ru.TypeTag, T: ru.TypeTag] = ru.typeOf[T] <:< ru.typeOf[S]
     |      | checkType: [S, T](implicit evidence$1: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[S], implicit evidence$2: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T])Boolean

scala>  checkType[Any, String]
res0: Boolean = true

scala>  checkType[Int, String]
res1: Boolean = false
```